# Appengine Backend shows twice the actual "Backend instance hours"

Tags: google-app-engine, backend

I have a Cron which pushes two tasks to a queue to be executed on a Backend:

//task 1

```
queue.add(withUrl("/tasks/<mytask>").param(..).header("Host", backendService.getBackendAddress("<mybackendname>")));
```

//task 2

```
queue.add(withUrl("/tasks/<mytask>").param(..).header("Host", backendService.getBackendAddress("<mybackendname>")));
```

I want these tasks (both tasks are same) to be executed one after another. This is my queue config:

```
<queue>
        <name><myqueuename></name>
        <rate>1/m</rate>
        <max-concurrent-requests>1</max-concurrent-requests>
        <bucket-size>1</bucket-size> 
        <retry-parameters>
            <task-retry-limit>1</task-retry-limit>
            <min-backoff-seconds>10</min-backoff-seconds>
            <max-backoff-seconds>200</max-backoff-seconds>
            <max-doublings>2</max-doublings>
        </retry-parameters>
</queue>
```

Now the problem is that the Backend starts executing the Task but it seems to consume double the amount of instance hours. So after one hour of Backend execution, the Backend Dashboard shows 2x the hours.
My Queue shows "Running=1" and "Tasks in Queue=2"
I have verified that the "Instances" for the Backend is only 1.0

[image]

As you can see from the attached picture, the Backend ran for ~4 hours, but the Table shows ~8 hours of Instance hours.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: How have you configured the backend? Is it a 'B2'?

Comment: Yes Greg, it was B2 (changed it to B1 today).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to have resolved by itself and I no longer see it on subsequent runs.